# Internet Explorer Automation Frame Notification Bar using Visual Basic SSIS Script task and UIAutomation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ui-automation, ie-automation

I am using a Visual Basic script task in Visual Studio's SSIS to automate downloading an excel file from https://www.fincen.gov/msb-registrant-search.

I have no issues with navigating to the site and clicking on the blue View/Download link.

The issue I am having is when the yellow "Frame Notification Bar" comes up and I need to programatically click on "Save". (I would prefer not to use the SendKeys method.)

I am using the UIAutomation reference to accomplish this.

I am also open to other suggestions other than using UIAutomation on how to download this file - the solution must be able to be used as part of a SSIS Package.

I have written this code in Excel VBA and it runs fine, however I am having issues translating the code to VB.

After successfully clicking on the download link, here is the code I run to do the following:

1. Find the notification bar hWnd
2. Read the text in the notification bar to
   determine the exact file name since it changes every time (I will be working 
   with the file after it downloads)
3. Click on the save button
4. Check the text in the notification bar to determine when
   the download has completed.

*I can provide the Excel VBA Code that works if that would help.

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports UIAutomationClient
Imports UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds
Imports UIAutomationClient.UIA_PatternIds
#End Region


<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr

Public CUIAuto As IUIAutomation
Public WindowHandleElement As IUIAutomationElement
Public windowHandle As Long
Public tCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Public bCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Public tCtl As IUIAutomationElement
Public bCtl As IUIAutomationElement
Public dlStatus As String
Public InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

Public Sub Main()

getReport()


GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub



Public Sub getReport()
Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim iePage As mshtml.HTMLDocument
Dim msbExport As IHTMLElement


IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate("https://www.fincen.gov/fcn/financial_institutions/msb/msbstateselector.html#")

Do : Sleep(1000) : Loop Until IE.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False


iePage = CType(IE.Document, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
msbExport = iePage.getElementById("ExportExcelLink")
msbExport.click()

Do

windowHandle = IE.HWND
windowHandle = CLng(FindWindowEx(windowHandle, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString))
Sleep(1000)
Loop Until windowHandle > 0



CUIAuto = New CUIAutomation
WindowHandleElement = CUIAuto.ElementFromHandle(CType(windowHandle, IntPtr))

tCnd = CUIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_TextControlTypeId)
tCtl = WindowHandleElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, tCnd)
dlStatus = CType(tCtl.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId), String) 'get download status

bCnd = CUIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
bCtl = WindowHandleElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, bCnd) ' The error seems to be happening here, there is no object after running this line
InvokePattern = CType(bCtl.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId), IUIAutomationInvokePattern)
InvokePattern.Invoke()


End Sub



#Region "ScriptResults declaration"
'This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
'result of the script.

'This code was generated automatically.
Enum ScriptResults
Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
End Enum

#End Region

End Class
```

**References:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. Here is the entire working code.

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports UIAutomationClient
Imports UIAutomationClient.UIA_PropertyIds
Imports UIAutomationClient.UIA_PatternIds
'Imports UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
#End Region


<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As IntPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr

Public CUIAuto As IUIAutomation
Public WindowHandleElement As IUIAutomationElement
Public windowHandle As Long
Public tCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Public bCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Public tCtl As IUIAutomationElement
Public bCtl As IUIAutomationElement
Public dlStatus As String
Public fileName As String
Public InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

Public Sub Main()


    getReport()
    'deleteRows()


    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub

Sub deleteExistingExtract()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim fPath As String

    fPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\downloads\152*"

    StrFile = Dir(fPath)
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Kill(fPath)
        StrFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub

Public Sub getReport()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim iePage As mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Dim msbExport As IHTMLElement


    IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate("https://www.fincen.gov/fcn/financial_institutions/msb/msbstateselector.html#")
    'On Error Resume Next
    Do : Sleep(1000) : Loop Until IE.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False


    iePage = CType(IE.Document, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
    msbExport = iePage.getElementById("ExportExcelLink")
    msbExport.click()

    Do
        'On Error Resume Next
        windowHandle = IE.HWND
        windowHandle = CLng(FindWindowEx(windowHandle, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString))
        Sleep(1000)
    Loop Until windowHandle > 0



    CUIAuto = New CUIAutomation
    WindowHandleElement = CUIAuto.ElementFromHandle(CType(windowHandle, IntPtr))

    tCnd = CUIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, UIA_ControlTypeIds.UIA_TextControlTypeId)
    tCtl = WindowHandleElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, tCnd)
    dlStatus = CType(tCtl.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId), String)
    fileName = Mid(dlStatus, InStr(dlStatus, "1"), 14)
    bCnd = CUIAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")
    bCtl = WindowHandleElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.TreeScope_Subtree, bCnd)
    InvokePattern = CType(bCtl.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId), IUIAutomationInvokePattern)
    InvokePattern.Invoke()


    Do
        dlStatus = CType(tCtl.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId), String)
        Sleep(1000)
    Loop Until Right(Trim(dlStatus), 10) = "completed."

    IE.Quit()

End Sub

#Region "ScriptResults declaration"
    'This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    'result of the script.

    'This code was generated automatically.
    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum

#End Region

End Class
```